# How do I run a function on a user level thread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

So I'm creating my own thread library and to start off I have two functions **system_init()** and **uthread create(void (* func)( ))** the first of which is supposed to initialize my program for handling user threads and the second which creates a thread that runs the function provided. These functions are as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>



std::queue<ucontext_t> *readyQueue;
int numKernelThreads;
int numIOWaitingProcesses;
sem_t sem;

void system_init() {
        numKernelThreads = 0;
        numIOWaitingProcesses = 0;
        sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
}



int uthread_create(void (* func)()) {
        ucontext_t context;
        getcontext(&context);
        makecontext(&context, func, 0);
        readyQueue->push(context);
}
```

I am having a few problems with it. First off I don't know how to run the function I provide in **uthread_create()**. Secondly I am getting segmentation faults when I push the context onto the queue. I'm just completely lost and would appreciate some direction. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/create-threads-in-linux/ .As for segfault, try allocating the queue first...

Comment: You are mixing c and c++

Comment: @AlterMann is there a problem with that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know how to create threads using pthread but I am making my own basic implementation. I've initialized the queue and it changes nothing.

Comment: I don't see any initialization in the code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've done so on my side and it changed nothing. The queue is really the least of my problems though. I don't know how to run the whole context idea works to run the function.

Comment: This is a very nice article: http://nitish712.blogspot.ca/2012/10/thread-library-using-context-switching.html

Comment: @Locke,  `stdio.h` is deprecated in c++ and `std::queue` is not valid in c

Comment: "I don't know how to run the function" - did you read the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext)? "When this context is later activated (using setcontext(3) or swapcontext()) the function func is called"

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes I attempted to read the doc and I think we can both agree that it isn't very user friendly.

Comment: @Locke: Friendly or not, it tells you what to do. Use `setcontext(&context)` to switch to that context and call the function.

Answer (score 1):

To run the function in `uthread_create()`, you need to push `func` onto the stack. Initialize the stack with something like

```
char* stack = new char[STACK_SIZE];
context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
context.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
```

where `STACK_SIZE` is some pre-defined constant (the constant `SIGSTKSZ` should work). After that, push `func` (and its relevant arguments) onto the stack.

The reason your getting segmentation faults is because the `ucontext_t` type contains a pointer to itself, and when you push it directly onto the queue you're making a copy. Then, the new copy points to the old data member, and when the old data member gets deleted, you will have a segfault. Instead, make a queue of pointers to `ucontext_t` and proceed from there.